# Is it possible to filter on Open Extensions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking to decide on Open Extensions vs. Schema Extensions.

Schema Extensions I know I can filter on, but I end up with an ugly schema name since I don't have any valid tld registered. This is not a blocker, just a small irritation :)

I'm adding custom metadata to a Group, and want to limit a query to all Groups having a specific metadata value. Is this doable using Open Extensions?

All OData variations I have tried using `/groups?$filter=` seem to give errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open extensions do not support filtering.  To filter on custom data, you will need to use schema extensions. Do you have any challenges registering a custom domain? Schema extensions now supports a few more TLDs (like .net and .org).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you. We have .no here in Norway, but I'll make do with a random name. Just have to add it as a variable for my component.

Comment: The issue is for a multi-tenant app, where the schema will have different names per tenant. I'll solve this my fetching all schemas, and see which ends with my name - as $filter does not support endsWith. Quirky, but doable.

Comment: Sorry - missing something fundamental here.  Why does the schema have a different name in each tenant?  The schema extension name/namespace (if made `Available`) should be the same/usable across all tenants.

Comment: I assumed the prefix will be randomly generated per tenant? Or will it be the same? If so, that is great. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: It's the same for every tenant (i.e. tenant independent).  I guess we need to make that clearer in the docs?

Comment: Could be an idea... and awesome. So I create my schema, get a random prefix - and that prefix will work all over. That makes generic solutions more viable and easier for sure :)

Comment: This is not correct. I can in one tenant create a schema named "Foo" multiple times, every one gets a random prefix (ext{8-random-alphanumeric-chars}_Foo.) . Creating the same schema "Foo" in another tenant yields yet another random prefix different from the others.

Comment: I think you are confusing concepts here Mikael. You only need to define the schema ONCE (if you make it `Available`). Once you do that you can reference it to add schematized/strongly typed data to entity instances of the extension schema's specified target type, *in any tenant*.  Does this make sense? Please take a look at the example in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups.

Comment: You are indeed right, and this is super scary. I see my schema extbufqc89t_CollaborationMetadata is now available for all tenants. And this is why so many schemas pop up when querying. The docs should be super clear on this, so that you don't use property names which could identify information. Maybe it's better to have the schema InDevelopment then, so as not to publish it to the world.