# How to filter Microsoft Graph events by OpenTypeExtensions

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

There seem to be plenty of examples of filtering by single and `multiValueExtendedProperties` in Microsoft Graph but these seem to be legacy. How do you filter by an `OpenTypeExtension` created like so?

```cs
ev.Extensions.Add(new OpenTypeExtension() { 
   AdditionalData = bag, 
   Id = Constants.LibraryId 
});
```

The ultimate goal is to filter events by whether our library created them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create these as Schema extensions (registering the shape of the extension in advance), or as open extensions? [In order to use the filter operation on extended properties, you'll need to be using Schema extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054414/is-it-possible-to-filter-on-open-extensions/46058783). In that case, you can filter as you normally would on an resource's property (eg. `~/me/messages?$filter=myExtension/favoriteColor eq 'green'`). [Here is more information about creating schema extensions on Graph resources](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension).

Comment: These shapes, once registered, apply to the specified resources for the entire tenant/organisation, then? Also, it looks like you've referenced the beta docs by accident. Here is v1.0. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/schemaextension

Comment: Upated with the correct link. Once the shape of the extension is registerd, they are discoverable by other applications as well.